# "Pyrcc5' ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm creating a plugin on QGIS for which I'm trying to compile the resources so I can start using it.

I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GccxvQ1ypbc roughly around the 3:45 mark.

Plugin is created then I get another message tied to pyrcc5 just like in the video.

[image]

I open OSGeo4W Shell in admin mode, I go straight to my plugin's directory and I get this error upon following the same steps the person in the video is doing:

[image]

`Le module spécifié est introuvable`  means `The specified module could not be found`

Please help, I have no clue what could be the issue. This is what my plugin directory upon creating looks like:

[image]

Comment: 3.16 my good sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in:

**Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization**

click in View Tab for uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types" option. Afterward, create a Windows Batch file (.bat extension) with the following content:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo on
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

and save it inside your plugin as **compile.bat**. In my example plugin (fortextthings), it was saved in following path:

```
C:\Users\zeito\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\fortextthings
```

Open a Command prompt and type your equivalent following commands (as follows, it has my plugin path):

```
cd C:\Users\zeito\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\fortextthings [Enter]
compile.bat [Enter]
```

As result, it was printed following text without any error message:

```
C:\Users\zeito\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\fortextthings>pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

and, afterward, my plugin was activated in "Manage and Install plugins" menu without any problem.